# GCD with large powers and Modulus

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, programming

Given three Values A , B , N

Find GCD ( ( ( A^N) + (B^N) ) , (A-B) )

where A,B,N <= 10^12

For more details : < https://www.codechef.com/AUG18B/problems/GCDMOD/ >

Comment: Thank you for being honest about the source of the problem.  Unfortunately, for obvious reasons it is against site policy to post questions from ongoing competitions.  I suggest you delete this until the contest ends.